# How to declare a Javascript variable such that it's cached in a for/loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
let data = '';
for (var ctr = 0; ctr < 1000000; ctr++) {
    data += "a";
}

console.log(data.length);

console.time('#1');
for (var ctr = 0; ctr < data.length; ctr++) {
}
console.timeEnd('#1');
```

TIME: 2.518ms

```
let data = '';
for (var ctr = 0; ctr < 1000000; ctr++) {
    data += "a";
}

console.log(data.length);

console.time('#2');
for (var ctr = 0; ctr < 1000000; ctr++) {
}
console.timeEnd('#2');
```

TIME: 2.184ms

```
let data = '';
for (var ctr = 0; ctr < 1000000; ctr++) {
    data += "a";
}

console.log(data.length);

const ctrLen = 1000000;

console.time('#3');
for (var ctr = 0; ctr < ctrLen; ctr++) {
}
console.timeEnd('#3');
```

TIME: 2.277ms

Is there a way in JavaScript to declare a variable that is cached so it's not evaluated over and over again? In the above examples, you can see in #2, that when I use a constant (1000000) instead of ".length," the routine is faster. What's the best way to create a performant loop?

Comment: you are modifing `data` in each iteration, so what kind of sense would a caching make or what do you expect?

Comment: This level of optimization is almost never something worth spending time on.  The optimizing compiler is really, really good with `for` loops in most cases.  Besides, you're measuring a pretty small delta on one million iterations.  0.33ms delta for one million iterations.  Is that really relevant?  That's really, really, really tiny per iteration.

Comment: I'm trying to make my code as performant as possible as a sort of academic exercise. I agree the speed increase is minimal, but I'm trying to squeeze everything I can out of nodejs. Is there a place online that lists the most performance routines? e.g., fastest way to loop, fastest way to access a database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the length in a variable beforehand.

```
for (let ctr = 0, len = data.length; ctr < len; ctr++) {
   //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you hev1, I will run a test later, but from other research, this appears to be the most readable and performant.

Answer (score 2):

Just get the length first:

```
const length = data.length
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {}
```